# How to get rid of the redundant "utilize" and "use"

Tags: phrase-request, redundancy

Is there any way to restate "Please utilize for productive use" without the redundant utilize and use?

Comment: "Please make good use of ..."  It seems to me the sentence is triply redundant since "to be productive" already implies the effective *use* of something.  Unless this is just an exercise, of course.

Comment: This depends on the context. Does it mean "Please utilize for productive use only"? Are there unproductive uses?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few alternatives:

- Please utilize productively
- Please use productively
- Please refrain from applications which are not productive
- Please refrain from unproductive applications

etc.

Answer (score -2):

It's not clear in what context the phrase appears, but, "Please utilize for production." is sufficient.

Comment: "Production" and "productive", while related, are not directly synonymous, and "productive use" carries connotations that the noun simply doesn't have..

Comment: That is why I prefaced the answer with "context." It seemed like the kind of statement that would be posted at a factory. It is, indeed, redundant. If someone is "utilizing" something, then they are making use of it. If they are making use of it than it is presumed they are using it for some kind of productive activity. If the statement has some purpose other than using item A to produce item B, I apologize for misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Not all uses are productive ones. Example: any game ever.